# Possible to modify every first tuple element in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need your help, I have a structure like this:

```
myList = [(1,2,3),(2,4,4),(1,5,6)]
```

It's a list of tuples. Now I need to get every first element of each tuple in the list to e.g. replace each `1` with a `3`.

The output should be: `myList = [(3,2,3),(2,4,4),(3,5,6)]`

I know I can make it like:

```
for item in myList:
   if item[0] == 1:
      item[0] = 3
```

But is there a other way to do this? Without iterating over the whole list?

Something like: `myList.getFirstItemOfEachTuple.replace(1,3)`

EDIT: I could change the `myList` to `[[1,2,3,4,5,6]...]` if necessary.

Comment: I can change the structure to a list

Comment: if You are interested in every first element why this line is present ```if item[0] == 1``` ?

Comment: Please give better examples. If you want a sequences as a result, specify a sequence with at least three items as input and a result sequence.

Comment: added a output and other input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> myList = [(1,2,3,4,5,6),(4,5,6,7,8)]
>>> dic = {1:3}
>>> [ (dic.get(x[0],x[0]),) + x[1:] for x in myList]
[(3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

If `myList` is a list of lists:

```
>>> myList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7,8]]
>>> [ [dic.get(x[0],x[0]) ] + x[1:] for x in myList]
[[3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

to modify the original list:

```
>>> myList[:] = [(dic.get(x[0],x[0]),) + x[1:] for x in myList]
>>> myList
[(3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

Comment: and how to make it if the orginal list is a list of lists and not a list of tuples?

Comment: @gurehbgui use this then : `[ [dic.get(x[0],x[0])] + x[1:] for x in myList]`

Comment: one more thing: what is i want to replace the second entry and not the first in the list/tuple?

Comment: @gurehbgui This should work then : `[ x[:1] + [dic.get(x[1],x[1]) ] + x[2:] for x in myList]`

Answer (score 3):

> *But is there a other way to do this? without iterating over the whole list?*

No. Not without iterating over the whole list.

Since you wish to examine each tuple to see if the element you wish to change is a certain number, you *have* to iterate over the whole list *somehow*. So the only remaining consideration is *how* to do it.

There exist good, time-tested and industry-standard guidelines that help decide how to write code: when writing code you should have **code readability** as a *first* priority. Code efficiency comes in as a distant second. There are exceptions to this rule, but they're not relevant here.

Look at your original code. It assumes `item` is a `list`, so I will too:

```
for item in myList:
    if item[0] == 1:
        item[0] = 3
```

Now compare with Ashwini's suggestion:

```
dic = {1: 3}
myList[:] = [[dic.get(x[0], x[0])] + x[1:] for x in myList]
```

Now ask yourself:

- Which one is easiest to read and understand? I think the answer is obvious.
- Which one is more efficient?

Let's look at the efficiency:

- **Your original code:** For each item in `myList`, perform a single list lookup and then possibly a single list assignment, both extremely fast operations.
- **Ashwinis code:** Rebuild the entire structure. For each item in `myList` python needs to create *three* new lists (*five* if you want to change an item that's not the first). Python must allocate new memory for each list and garbage collect a lot of old lists, both rather slow operations. All for the sake of cramming it into a one-liner.

*Please*, go with your original code. Here's why:

- It's the *obvious* way to do it.
- It's the *pythonic* way to do it.
- It's the *most readable* way to do it.
- It's the *most efficient* way to do it.

Which means it's the *right* way to do it.

If you want a one-liner, make it a function:

```
def conditional_sublist_assign(myList, index, from, to):
    """
    For each `item` in `myList`, set `item[index] = to` if `item[index] == from`.
    """
    for item in myList:
        if item[index] == from:
            item[index] = to

# Here's your one-liner:
conditional_sublist_assign(myList, 0, 1, 3)
```

To lend some more weight to my arguments, here are some relevant lines from [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Simple is better than complex.
- Readability counts.
- There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
- If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Comment: +1, for "If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea"... if only that was my mantra... unfortunately I am the one liner type :'(

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehensions.

Condition first tuple item must be 1:

```
>>> L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [[3] + x[1:] if x[0] == 1 else x for x in L]
[[3, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Solution for tuples instead of lists inside the list:

```
>>> L = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
>>> [(3,)  + x[1:] if x[0] == 1 else x  for x in L]
[(3, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Comment: "get every first element of each tuple in the list to e.g. replace each 1 with a 3." Contradicts the code of the OP though.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in numpy, numpy is also 50 times faster than python so if speed is important, that is definatly the way to go:

```
import numpy as np
myList = [(1,2,3),(2,4,4),(1,5,6)]
# convert list of tuples to 2D numpy array
myList = np.array(myList)
# get an array of all first element, syntax: myList[x, y] x and w and be ranges 1:3 og numbers like 1
# all the first elements are as follows:
first = myList[:,0]
# you can then make a true / false vector as follows
myList[first == 1,0] = 3
print myList
# prints:
#[[3 2 3]
# [2 4 4]
# [3 5 6]]
```

Comment: Nice solution, +1. But OP, keep in mind that numpy is a non-builtin module. Also, it's quite expensive to import, so a pure python solution gets a good head start. This means you need to do *a lot* of number crunching to "catch up", so to speak, and make using numpy actually pay off in run time.

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow, Thanks, import numpy takes 0.15-0.2 sec on my computer, however making a numpy array from a python list/tuple is unfortunately more expensive than looping trough the entire list... so my trick is worthless if he only needs it once pr list :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't change the value of tuple, it's immutable. But you convert tuple to list and change the value